# How send message when insert or replace is empty. - JAVA / MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql

I use a parser to read data from a text file and writes them to the database. I wanted to find a way when the reading is made ​​empty more than 2 times send an error message.

how can I do this?

This is possible?

The code of parser is that:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/RPR1BRG/Desktop/test.txt"));

String dados[] = new String[6];
String linha = reader.readLine();

while (linha != null) {

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(linha, ";\"");

    dados[0] = st.nextToken();
    dados[1] = st.nextToken(); 
    dados[2] = st.nextToken();
    dados[3] = st.nextToken();
    dados[4] = st.nextToken();
    dados[5] = st.nextToken();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yy");

    PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) conexao.prepareStatement("replace into registos" + " (date, hour, Id, Tem, Hum, pt) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    try {
        stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(dateFormat.parse(dados[0]).getTime()));
        stmt.setString(2, dados[1]);
        stmt.setString(3, dados[2]);
        stmt.setString(4, dados[3]);
        stmt.setString(5, dados[4]);
        stmt.setString(6, dados[5]);

    } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }

    stmt.executeUpdate();


    linha = reader.readLine();

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/RPR1BRG/test.txt"); 
    writer.print("");
    writer.close();                
}

} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
```

I hope I have been explicit in doubt.

If someone can not understand ask me to clarify.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could add a flag `boolean` that you set when you hit an empty line, and then if the next line is empty as well you error out, otherwise you reset the flag.

```
boolean flag = false;
while (line = in.read() != null) {
    if (line.equals("") && flag) throw Exception();
    else if (line.equals("")) flag = true;
    else flag = false
    ...
}
```

That is just some psuedocode but should get my point across.

Comment: thanks for the reply. 
You say to add this code before the catch?

Comment: No, that would be your while loop in there. I just wrote mine a little differently.